# The users variable appears to be empty for will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I am following the Railcast tutorial on endless page. I am receiving a Argument Error `The @users variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?`

The javascript has been modified so you have to click a read more link to get more results. So the pagination will work by click instead of scrolling.

The error points to the line `<%= will_paginate @questions %>`

Questions Controller:

```
      def index
#Before gem added it was `@questions = Question.all`
        @questions = Question.order("question").page(params[:users]).per_page(2)    
        respond_with(@questions)
    end
```

Users Controller:

```
  def profile
    @profile = User.profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
    @question = Question.where(recipient_id: params[:id]).first
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @question = Question.where(recipient_id: params[:id])
  end
```

View:

```
<% @question.select(&:answer?).each do |question| %>
Question: <%= question.question %>
<br>
Answer: <%= question.answer %><br><br>

<%= will_paginate @questions %>
<% end %>
```

Questions.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $('#append_and_paginate').prepend('<a id="append_more_results" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more questions</a>');
    $('#append_more_results').click ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url
        $('.pagination').text('Fetching more questions...')
        $.getScript(url)
```

Index.js.erb:

```
$('#questions').append('<%= j render(@questions) %>');
<% if @questions.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@questions) %>');
<% else %>
  $('#append_and_paginate').remove();
<% end %>
<% sleep 1 %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
    @questions = Question.order("question").page(params[:users]).per_page(2)
```

With

```
     @questions = Question.order("question").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
```

**EDIT**

Update the User model as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :sender_questions, :class_name => 'Question', :foreign_key => 'sender_id' 
  has_many :recipient_questions, :class_name => 'Question', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

end
```

Update the UsersController#show action as below:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  @question = @user. recipient_questions.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Can you share the error stacktrace in the question.

Comment: It seems like you are calling `will_paginate @users` in one of the views and @users is not set. It would be easier to resolve your issue if you provide stacktace in the question.

Comment: The error shows only if the answer to the question is not NULL. With the other test accounts, their Questions that have not been answered loads the profile fine, however once I add a answer the page spits out the same error.

Comment: In my Users controller (just added) if I change `@question = Question.where(recipient_id: params[:id])` to `@question = @user.questions.paginate(page: params[:id])` I get the error ``Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'questions.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `questions`.* FROM `questions`  WHERE `questions`.`user_id` = 2 LIMIT 30 OFFSET 30`` So I need to have it read from the recipient_id column that exists.

Comment: What is the name of the view that you have shared in the question?